# Query doesn't insert values in sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have a problem that is haunting me a few days. All I want to do is add a command inside the method 'ViewDidLoad' which will make entering data into sqlite, which would make it simple do not need other fields and buttons, so, on the simulation runs, the new record will be inserted automatically in sqlite, so I try this:

1. In SQLite Manager Database (Plugin in firefox), I create a New Database who name is 'registros', and the program save it 'registros.sqlite'
2. I create this table:

   CREATE  TABLE "main"."campos" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "campo1" VARCHAR, "campo2" VARCHAR, "campo3" VARCHAR)

In my project file, all I did was, create a file who name is 'MYFristViewController' with xib file, In the 'build Phases' I add the 'libsqlite3.dylib'. In the MyFristViewController.m I add this code:

```
#import "MyFristViewController.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>

@implementation MyFristViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    sqlite3 *db;

    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"registros.sqlite"];

    sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db);

    char *sql = "INSERT INTO campos (campo1,campo2,campo3) VALUES (?,?,?)";

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    int resultado2 = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, nil);

    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [@"Campo_01" UTF8String], -1,  SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [@"Campo_02" UTF8String], -1,  SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [@"Campo_03" UTF8String], -1,  SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    resultado2 = sqlite3_step(stmt);

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

}

@end
```

As a beginner I'm not sure what else to do, I even tried modifying the fifth parameter of the command 'sqlite3_bind_text' to SQLITE_STATIC or SQLITE_TRANSIENT, but it seems that the values ​​were not added to the database, could someone help me?

Comment: You need to check the return values of `sqlite3_open`, `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, and `sqlite3_step`. Also, it's better to use `sqlite3_open_v2` instead of the old `sqlite3_open`. Also, an app's bundle is read-only. You can't write a file there so you need to put your database file in a writable location when you app is first run.

Comment: And if one of the return codes is not "good", log the value of `sqlite3_errmsg()`.  The error reporting in SQLite is excellent, but you have to actually make use of it.

Comment: Generally the CREATE TABLE should be `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST`, so that you don't error out the second time you access the DB.

Comment: Also, to learn how to use SQLite and test out your queries, use the `sqlite3` OSX command in a command window to open and manipulate a test file.  The command can also be used to examine the contents of the DB file you create in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

to create a new register in database, in .h file (Inherited NSObject), do you need import sqlite3.h, get the path of database:

```
@interface RegistroCrud : NSObject{
    sqlite3 *bd;
}
-(NSString *) getPathBD;
-(void)newRegister:(NSString *)campo1 campo2:(NSString *)campo2 campo3:(NSString *)campo3;
```

getPathDB method is to get the database if does exits, or create it if does not exits

in .m file:

```
-(NSString *)getPathBD
{
    NSString *dirDocs;
    NSArray *rutas;
    NSString *rutaBD;
    rutas = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    dirDocs = [rutas objectAtIndex:0];

    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    rutaBD = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[dirDocs       
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"registros.sqlite"]];

    if([fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:rutaBD] == NO){
        [fileMgr copyItemAtPath:[[[NSBundle     mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"registros.sqlite"] toPath:rutaBD error:NULL
         ];
    }
    return rutaBD;
    }

-(void)newRegister:(NSString *)campo1 campo2:(NSString *)campo2 campo3:(NSString *)campo3
{
    NSString *pathDB = [self getPathBD];
    if(!(sqlite3_open([pathDB UTF8String], &bd) == SQLITE_OK)){
        NSLog(@"No se puede conectar con la BD");
        return;
    } else {
        NSString *sqlInsert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR IGNORE INTO campos (campo1,campo2,campo3) VALUES (%@,%@,'%@')",campo1,campo2,campo3];
        const char *sql = [sqlInsert UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(bd, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"Problema al preparar el statement");
            return;
        } else {
            if(sqlite3_step(sqlStatement) == SQLITE_DONE){
                sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
                sqlite3_close(bd);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you need have the registros.sqlite in the project

there is a tutorial in spanish: http://www.imaginaformacion.com/tutoriales/crear-una-aplicacion-con-sql-lite-en-ios-5-parte-i/ to make crud in database in ios with sqlite, ;)

Comment: I'm getting error the error on console 'Problema al preparar el statement', I continue with 'MyFristController.h/.m/.xib' in the .h file I put <NSObject>, and the rest is the same...

Comment: AAAH in the .m file in the method viewDidLoad I'm put this code: [self getPathBD];
[self newRegister:@"ws" campo2:@"gh" campo3:@"fg"];

Comment: Do you need to create a new class (i.e: registroCrud), Inherited from NSObject and in your viewController import this class (i.e: #import "registroCrud.h"), and to create new register in database:
registroCrud *register = [[registroCrud alloc]init];
[register newRegister:@"campo1"campo2:@"campo2"campo3:@"campo3"];

Comment: here is the project file: www.fazerbem.com.br/TesteUltimoSql.zip

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things but did not get any results, here I leave with you the files of my project:

www.fazerbem.com.br/TesteUltimoSql.zip